# .Net Maui List Assets Under Resources Raw Folder

Tags: .net, assets, maui, embedded-resource

**The Context.**

I'm working on .net Maui mobile app that uses some native android libraries with dependencies on bunch of configuration files provided by vendor. These files should be placed into data folder in order for drivers to work properly. So ideally, at app startup, you just iterate over, say, `\Resources\Raw\DriverConfigs\*.cfg`  folder content and copy each file into `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory` using stream reader/writer. While files have `Build Action = MauiAsset` properties.

**The problem and current workaround.**

Now the problem is that there seems no good way to get a list of files within Raw folder. I can do it one by one providing actual resource name as described by MS help [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows#writing-from-a-bundled-file-to-the-app-data-folder) but again, I need to get a list of resources first in order to iterate over the files.
So I end-up with following workaround. I've crated separate folder within a project, and put all my driver config files in there as `Embedded Resource`. So now I can easily iterate over and extract them using the following code:

```
       private static void ExtractDriverConfigs()
       {
           var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;            
           
           foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
           {
               if (res.Contains(".cfg"))
               {
                   // read source file 
                   using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(res);
                   using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                   var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                   // generate target path inside data folder
                   string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, res);
                   
                   // write file into data folder
                   using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
                   using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);

                   streamWriter.Write(content);
               }
           }
       }
```

That workaround works like a charm. Still I think it is too much, and there should be better framework provided way to do it using existing Raw resources .net maui feature.

**The actual question.**

Sorry for the long intro. Basically the question is whether there is better way to do it using framework provided tools. It is sad I can't solve it using existing framework provided features around Raw Resources. Perhaps someone knows if there is any other way to get Raw asset apart from existing `await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);` method.

Appreciate any ideas on this. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such an official framework you want, the method official document provide is suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As you are working on android you can use platform related code, for example:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> ListAssets(string subfolder)
 {
    AssetManager assets = Platform.AppContext.Assets;
    string[] files = assets.List(subfolder);
    return files;
 }
```

Let's say you have files inside "Resources/Raw/DriverConfigs" then calling `ListAssets("DriverConfigs");` will be able to list your your files in that subfolder with build action set to MauiAsset, and you can then filter them manually by extension etc.

Test:

```
            var files= App.Native.ListAssets("DriverConfigs");    
            var fileName = files.First(); //will throw if no files..

            try
            {
                using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync($"DriverConfigs/{fileName}");
                using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

**Bonus iOS + Windows:**

```
 public IEnumerable<string> ListAssets(string subfolder)
        {
            NSBundle mainBundle = NSBundle.MainBundle;
            string resourcesPath = mainBundle.ResourcePath;
            string subfolderPath = Path.Combine(resourcesPath, subfolder);

            if (Directory.Exists(subfolderPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(subfolderPath);
                return files.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> ListAssets(string sub)
        {
            StorageFolder installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder subfolder = installFolder.GetFolderAsync(sub).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = subfolder.GetFilesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return files.Select(f => f.Name);
        }
```